# How to integrate React native navigation with AWS Amplify push notifications in android?

Tags: react-native-navigation, aws-amplify, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am trying to get FCM push notifications working in my react native project for android with react-native-notification library and aws-amplify. I have an issue with PushNotification.onRegister method is not called in android to get device token to send remote notifications.How can I make these two library working together in my react native project?

I followed aws-amplify documentation https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?ref=amplify-rn-btn&platform=react-native
to include amplify library in react native project.
I then added push notifications set up as per https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/push-notifications
I have included react-native-navigation library to support navigation in my react-native app as per 
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing
After the installation react-native navigation library pushNotification.onRegister method is not getting called to receive device token without which I am unable to send push notifications in android.

I have push notifications configured in App.js as per below

```
 import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification';
 import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';
 import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
 // retrieve temporary AWS credentials and sign requests
 Auth.configure(awsconfig);
// send analytics events to Amazon Pinpoint
Analytics.configure(awsconfig);
console.log(PushNotification);
PushNotification.configure(awsconfig);
```

Then in the constructor of App.js I am registering for PushNotification events.

```
 Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    PushNotification.onNotification((notification) => {
      // Note that the notification object structure is different    from Android and IOS
      console.log('in app notification', notification);

      // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    });

    // get the registration token
    PushNotification.onRegister((token) => {
      Alert.alert(token);
   this.setState({token:token});
      console.log('in app registration', token);
    });

    // get the notification data when notification is opened
    PushNotification.onNotificationOpened((notification) => {
        console.log('the notification is opened', notification);
    });
  });
```

This set up works fine and PushNotification.onRegister event is called and device token is getting printed if I don't include react-native-navigation library.
In iOS I am able to get device token with react-native-navigation library but in android it is not working. Any pointers on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2541#issuecomment-455245033

- the Android app calls `.onRegister()` once only, when the app/device is completely new. The calls afterwards seems to load from cache.

Comment: Yes, I had tried as per this in a standalone react native project and I am able to receive notification in android, but I use Wix's React Native Navigation library for the navigation within React Native App and with this it seems to be breaking and onRegister never gets called. You can reproduce this issue by adding react-native-navigation in the React Native amplify project